# Separate access levels for different apps in Django

Tags: django, authentication

I have 4 apps in my Django project. I want to create a login for each of them. But a user signed up for app1 shouldn't be able to access the pages of app2. If I give this user the access to app1 models only from django admin, he won't be able to affect the app2 models but will he still be able to view the pages created in app2?

I just want to display a permission denied message if such a user tries to login to app2. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

My opinion

### settings.py

```
USER_TYPES = [
          (1,'first'), 
         (2, 'second')]
```

### models.py

#### frist app

```
class User_First(models.Model):
    type = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=settings.USER_TYPES)
```

#### Second app

```
class User_Second(models.Model):
    type = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=settings.USER_TYPES)
```

### Views.py

if you use CBV at your apps

#### first_app

```
class BaseView(Views):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.type == 2:
            redirect(views of second app)
        else:
            super(BaseView, self).dispatch(request=request,*args,**kwargs)
```

#### second_app

```
class BaseView(Views):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.type == 1:
            redirect(views of second app)
        else:
            super(BaseView, self).dispatch(request=request,*args,**kwargs)
```

and then all views inherit from it